# Why i lost value in a row (SAS input;datalines problem)?

Tags: sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI56J.png)

Hello, in screenshot you can see that a value under "sex" column is missing, I have no clue exactly what happened here, only I know is that "10240" is causing it. How to manage with that? I would like to get "10240" value under "type" column, and value "1" under "sex" column.

Comment: Please post text as text, not photographs.

Answer (score 1):

Just count the number of characters.  You told SAS to read SEX from column 5.  On the first line column 5 is blank.

It looks like your data has spaces between the values and every variable has a value on every line so just use LIST MODE input instead of COLUMN MODE.

```
input type sex height weight ;
```